# [rospy] How do you unsubscribe to a topic, from within the callback?

Tags: ros, rospy, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a previous [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/30490/rospy-suscriber-run-a-callback-once-using-rospyspin/) a similar issue was addressed but solved in another manner, however the solution suggsted:

```
def cb_once(msg, subscriber):
    #do processing here
    subscriber.unregister()

sub_once = None
sub_once = rospy.Subscriber('my_topic,', MyType, cb_once, sub_once)
```

However since you the right hand side of the last line has to finish before equating to the left hand side, thus sub_once point to wrong place, hence in the cb_once, subscriber.unregister() can't work. Is there another way?

Many Thanks

Guy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46613/%5Brospy%5D-how-do-you-unsubscribe-to-a-topic,-from-within-the-callback-?/) by [Phuicy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3452/phuicy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-10-23

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2013-07-02**:
When you say "can't work" do you mean "I don't think it works" or "I tried it and it doesn't work"?  The callback isn't called by Subscriber, although (I think that) there's a small chance that it will fire before Subscriber returns (very small, probably).

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2013-07-02**:
You can always wrap the callback code in a try block if you're worried that it will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know it's been over a year but I just had this same problem and found this post. Just make sub_once a global variable.

```
def cb_once(msg):
   #do processing here
   sub_once.unregister()

global sub_once
sub_once = rospy.Subscriber('my_topic,', MyType, cb_once)
```

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2013-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Phuicy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3452/phuicy/) on 2013-07-02**:
Thanks, I will try but I am skeptical. As the '''rospy.subscriber'' is processed first and the hence the callback ''cb_once" then ''sub_once = ", thus the '''sub_once" in the callback isnt point to the subscriber yet.

**Comment by [Phuicy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3452/phuicy/) on 2013-07-02**:
Btw, thank you for replying. It what makes a good community.

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-07-03**:
Wouldn't that be fixed by placing a `global sub_once` in the callback? (And moving the var to the top)

**Comment by [inkspell4](https://answers.ros.org/users/28072/inkspell4/) on 2017-02-26**:
I can confirm that this will work. cb_once will only be called when a message has been received at which point if `global sub_once` is included in both the callback and in the place making the subscriber the line `sub_once.unregister()` will reference the subscriber created even below it

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An easy way to get a single message is this:

```
 msg = rospy.wait_for_message("my_topic", MyType)
```

This returns the message, and shuts down after receiving one message. You can specify a timeout as the third argument. It also doesn't require using a global.

---

Originally posted by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) with karma: 287 on 2014-06-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-10-20**:
+1. Depending on the purpose though, I think this is cleaner and easier.